# Virtuemart - insert function into checkout

Tags: php, virtuemart

I am currently using Joomla 1.7.5 and Virtuemart 2.0.2 and need to intercept the checkout function and perform some actions before we move on to the "thank you" page.

The variables I need access to are the VM order ID (and items) the user's Joomla group and perhaps the shipping details for the order/user. I will then inject a few items into a custom table I have made to track some data.

Does anyone have information on where the checkout is kept so i can insert my function, and how i can access the variables I need (perhaps get the VM order ID and query the items etc from there .. and grab the joomla user group from $this->user->groups if it is available)./

any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

Answer (score 0):

The checkout class reside in `joomla\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\classes\ps_checkout.php`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Since it is php can i presume that all the joomla and jquery variables are available during checkout?

Comment: Maybe im using a different version than I think .. because i can't seem to locate a classes folder in virtuemart under administrator ..